# Kohanav3 ORM: calling where->find_all twice

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

When I do something like the following:

```
$site = ORM::factory('site')->where('name', '=', 'Test Site')->find();
$users = $site->users;
$deletedusers = $users->where('deleted', '=', '1')->find_all();
$nondeletedusers = $users->where('deleted', '=', '0')->find_all();
```

The contents of $deletedusers is correct, but the $nondeletedusers contains every non-deleted user, not just the ones in the loaded $site.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of `find_all()` and `find()` methods will reset your model state. For example, `$user` has a `where('site_id', '=', <site_id>)` condition (it was applied in the line#1 of your code). When you call `find_all()`, **ORM** resets all conditions, so `$nondeletedusers` works with empty model.

To avoid this behavior, you can try to `clone` $users, or retrieve all users ids from `$user` and add `AND WHERE id IN <id list>` condition.